# SSRS Subreport in tablix fails when multi parameter values are outside of subreport values

Tags: parameter-passing, subreport, reporting-services-2012

I have an SSRS 2012 report that contains a sub-report within a tablix. I do this to provide a copy of the sub-report for each of the customers selected in the main report's multi-value @CustomerID parameter.

I have a data-set called Customers that is linked to the tablix. From this the tablix passes the field called CustomerID to the sub-report's @CustomerID parameter (in the sub-report the @CustomerID parameter is not multi-value).

I then have 3 other multi-value parameters (@Assignedto, @OperationalArea and @SiteClass) that I need to pass through to the sub-report. I am passing these through using the Parameters matching on the sub-report properties (for instance Assignedto in the sub-report is matched to Parameters!Assignedto.Value in the main report).

My problem is that if I have customers 1 and 2 selected and the three parameters only have items selected that exist for both customers then the sub-reports run fine. However, if I have selected an item in the parameters that only exists for customer 1, then the sub-report will not run for customer 2 (even if there are valid items selected for customer 2 also). This problem is occurring for all three multi-value parameters that are passed through to the sub-report.

For instance:

1. Customer 1 and 2 selected alongside @Assignedto selections of Engineer 1 and Engineer 2 who both are valid selections for Customer 1 and Customer 2. In this instance sub-reports for Customer 1 and 2 will both be displayed.
2. Customer 1 and 2 selected alongside selections of Engineers 1, 2, 3. Engineers 1 and 2 are valid for both customers. Engineer 3 is only valid for customer 1. In this instance only the sub-report for customer 1 will be displayed, even though there is data for Engineers 1 and 2 for customer 2. I get an error message saying Error: Subreport could not be shown.

When I run the sub-report itself this runs fine, but the values for the multi-value parameters are determined by the value of the @CustomerID parameter (using data-sets), so I cannot select values outside of the valid values for that customer.

I have run the SQL for all the data-sets in the sub-report in SSMS using values for the parameters that are outside of values that exist for the customers. These all ran fine.

I have also tried switching between using and not using the join function with the data-set parameters in the sub-report, but this does not do anything.

I have also tried to pass the multi-valued parameters values from the main report using a comma delimited list via the below query, that limits the list to valid values for the customer. This did not solve the problem.

I am at a lost and any help would be much appreciated.

```
  IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Data_Sub') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Data_Sub;

Select distinct
        CustomerID
        ,[AssignedToUser]
        ,null as OperationalArea
        ,null as SiteClass
Into 
        #Data_Sub
from 
        [FAMSDB].[dbo].[Incidents_Full_PI] as IFPI
        inner join 
                    (
                            select 
                                        item 
                            from 
                                        [FAMSDB].[dbo].SplitToTable 
(@CustomerID,',')
                    ) as CID on IFPI.CustomerID = CID.item
where 
        ReportedFaultCode in ('SPD','SPO','SRD','SRO','SEO','SED')
        and CASE      when [AssignedToUser] in (select item from 
FAMSDB.dbo.SplitToTable(@Assignedto,',')) then 1
                      else 0
                      end = 1
Union
Select distinct
        CustomerID
        ,null
        ,OperationalArea
        ,null
from 
        [FAMSDB].[dbo].[Incidents_Full_PI] as IFPI
        inner join 
                    (
                            select 
                                        item 
                            from 
                                        [FAMSDB].[dbo].SplitToTable 
(@CustomerID,',')
                    ) as CID on IFPI.CustomerID = CID.item
where 
        ReportedFaultCode in ('SPD','SPO','SRD','SRO','SEO','SED')
        and CASE     when [OperationalArea] in (select item from 
FAMSDB.dbo.SplitToTable(@OperationalArea,',')) then 1
                     else 0
                     end = 1
Union
Select distinct
        CustomerID
        ,null
        ,null
        ,SiteClass
from 
        [FAMSDB].[dbo].[Incidents_Full_PI] as IFPI
        inner join 
                    (
                            select 
                                        item 
                            from 
                                        [FAMSDB].[dbo].SplitToTable 
(@CustomerID,',')
                    ) as CID on IFPI.CustomerID = CID.item
where 
        ReportedFaultCode in ('SPD','SPO','SRD','SRO','SEO','SED')
         and CASE     when [SiteClass] in (select item from 
FAMSDB.dbo.SplitToTable(@SiteClass,',')) then 1
                     else 0
                     end = 1
union
select 
        item 
        ,case   when 'Unassigned' in (select item from 
 FAMSDB.dbo.SplitToTable(@Assignedto,',')) then 'Unassigned' 
                else null
                end 
        ,case   when 'Unassigned' in (select item from 
FAMSDB.dbo.SplitToTable(@OperationalArea,',')) then 'Unassigned' 
                else null
                end
        ,case   when 'Unassigned' in (select item from 
FAMSDB.dbo.SplitToTable(@SiteClass,',')) then 'Unassigned' 
                else null
                end
from 
        [FAMSDB].[dbo].SplitToTable (@CustomerID,',')

union
select 
        item 
        ,case   when 'N/A' in (select item from 
FAMSDB.dbo.SplitToTable(@Assignedto,',')) then 'N/A' 
                else null
                end 
        ,case   when 'N/A' in (select item from 
 FAMSDB.dbo.SplitToTable(@OperationalArea,',')) then 'N/A' 
                else null
                end
        ,case   when 'N/A' in (select item from 
 FAMSDB.dbo.SplitToTable(@SiteClass,',')) then 'N/A' 
                else null
                end
from 
        [FAMSDB].[dbo].SplitToTable (@CustomerID,',')


Select
        CustomerID
        ,AssignedToUser
        ,OperationalArea
        ,SiteClass
From
    (
        Select distinct
                CustomerID
                ,case   when len((Select [AssignedToUser]+',' From(Select 
Distinct CustomerID,[AssignedToUser] From #Data_Sub) as b Where b.CustomerID 
= a.CustomerID For XML Path('')))=0 then null
                        else LEft((Select 
                                [AssignedToUser]+','
                        From
                                (
                                    Select Distinct
                                        CustomerID
                                        ,[AssignedToUser]   
                                    From
                                            #Data_Sub
                                ) as b
                        Where
                                b.CustomerID = a.CustomerID
                        For XML Path(''))
                        ,len((Select 
                                        [AssignedToUser]+','
                                From
                                        (
                                            Select Distinct
                                                CustomerID
                                                ,[AssignedToUser]   
                                            From
                                                    #Data_Sub
                                        ) as b
                                Where
                                        b.CustomerID = a.CustomerID
                                For XML Path('')))-1
                    ) end as AssignedToUser
                 ,case  when len((Select [OperationalArea]+',' From(Select 
Distinct CustomerID,[OperationalArea] From #Data_Sub) as b Where 
b.CustomerID = a.CustomerID For XML Path('')))=0 then null
                        else left((Select 
                                [OperationalArea]+','
                        From
                                (
                                    Select Distinct
                                        CustomerID
                                        ,[OperationalArea]  
                                    From
                                            #Data_Sub
                                ) as b
                        Where
                                b.CustomerID = a.CustomerID
                    For XML Path('')),
                        lEn((Select 
                                        [OperationalArea]+','
                                From
                                        (
                                            Select Distinct
                                                CustomerID
                                                ,[OperationalArea]  
                                            From
                                                    #Data_Sub
                                        ) as b
                                Where
                                        b.CustomerID = a.CustomerID
                                For XML Path('')))-1
                        ) end as OperationalArea
                ,case   when len((Select [SiteClass]+',' From(Select 
Distinct CustomerID,[SiteClass] From #Data_Sub) as b Where b.CustomerID = 
a.CustomerID For XML Path('')))=0 then null
                        else Left((Select 
                                 [SiteClass]+','
                        From
                                (
                                    Select Distinct
                                        CustomerID
                                        ,[SiteClass]    
                                    From
                                            #Data_Sub
                                ) as b
                        Where
                                b.CustomerID = a.CustomerID
                        For XML Path(''))
                    ,len((Select 
                                 [SiteClass]+','
                        From
                                (
                                    Select Distinct
                                        CustomerID
                                        ,[SiteClass]    
                                    From
                                            #Data_Sub
                                ) as b
                        Where
                                b.CustomerID = a.CustomerID
                        For XML Path('')))-1
                    ) end as SiteClass
        From
                #Data_Sub as a
    ) as ConcatSub
where
        AssignedToUser is not null
        and OperationalArea is not null
        and SiteClass is not null
```

Edit: I have not tested the sub-report by removing the CustomerID filter on the dataset that returns the values for the multi-value parameters. So they can now have parameter values selected that are not valid for the Customer selection. The sub-report runs fine still. Therefore the problem must be in how the parameters are being passed to the sub-report.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this seems to have been a combination of having the sub-report able to select parameter values that were not filtered by the CustomerID, and passing the parameter in the [@Assignedto] form rather than as a delimited string or the =Parameters!Assignedto.Value form.

I tried both of these methods separately without result, but when combined they have fixed the problem.